# Skip rc.local while booting

Tags: boot, reboot

I'm running ubuntu-10.04.2-server, accidentally somebody put command "reboot" on rc.local, so when i started ubuntu it always restarting,
can i force ubuntu to not load rc.local?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reboot into recovery mode and fix your rc.local file.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode

Comment: thank you Steven Kath :), need the correct timing to press the shift button