# How to edit a protected file if I have no direct access to the filesystem?

Tags: 14.04, permissions, filesystem, live-usb, files

I changed the brightness of my machine by editing the `/etc/rc.local` file and adding this line `echo 10 > /sys/class/backlight/nv_backlight/brightness` before `exit 0`.

After reboot I can see that it works fine. The problem is, it's so dark that I can't see anything. The screen is completely black. I tried running a live USB to edit the file but I have no write permissions.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a bountiful bevy of options, I'll start with the easiest and work through:

- Do you have backlight control keys on your keyboard? Many laptops do and they might work here long enough to let you edit that file.
- If you have  previously installed a SSH server, you could SSH in from another computer and `sudo nano /etc/rc.local`. The same goes for other remote solutions NX/VNC/RDP will all let you get into a position where you're sitting with a terminal in front of you.
- Boot into Recovery Mode. [Apparently this won't load `rc.local`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/328761/skip-rc-local-while-booting). You'll need to run `mount -o remount,rw /` first but then you should be able to run `nano /etc/rc.local`.
- LiveUSB/CD: mount the disk somewhere and (from the command line) `sudo nano /media/.../etc/rc.local` — just remember to edit the mounted version, not the Live version.
- Jedi it. Boot up normally, <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>. Type your username followed by <kbd>Return</kbd>. Then your password and <kbd>Return</kbd>... And then *carefully* type in `sudo sed -i '/backlight/d' /etc/rc.local` followed by <kbd>Return</kbd>. Then type your password (for `sudo`) followed by <kbd>Return</kbd>. `sudo reboot` <kbd>Return</kbd> to safely reboot.